# Adding app.js to angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm triying to add bootstrap ui modules to an angular project. In every tutorial I read that after download the module i'm supposed to add a directive (**angular.module(for example: 'App', ['ui.carousel']**) to certain file that in some forums i've read is called app.js. This file doesnt exist in my project. The question is: Should I create it? Where? Is a controller necesary? How is the flow that this must follow? Then I should add it to the index.html?

Comment: whatever is in your `<script>`. Usually you want to add a **path** to a `.js` file (like `<script src="/app.js"></script>`), but your html can have just the script with the JavaScript code in it: `<script> angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']); </script>`

Comment: Hi! @AlekseySolovey Thanks for your answer. That would be in the component template where i'm using it or in the index.html file?

Comment: I was totally confused by angular versions and structure. Tryin to implement original angulaJS code into an angular 4+ app.

Answer (score 1):

*Getting advanced here with components without even knowing the basics.* I recommend starting with [just controllers](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#carousel) (without components). *But,* here is a basic example of how scripts are added:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<!-- Adding scripts here. The order matters: angular.js first, then its dependancies, e.g. ui-bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <div>

    <!-- main body -->
    <div>
      <hello-world name="World"> </hello-world>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- ng-template simulates a separate file -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="my_component.html">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model='$ctrl.name'><br><span>Hello {{$ctrl.name}}, I'm {{$ctrl.myName}}!</span>
  </script>



  <!-- This script can be also written as:
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  if the file `app.js` is located in root directory of the server, 
  which should contain the AngularJS code below
-->
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']); // injected dependancies

    app.component("helloWorld", {
      templateUrl: "my_component.html",
      /* component template */
      bindings: {
        name: '@'
      },
      controller: function() {
        this.myName = 'Karolyn'; // use of `this` requires `$ctrl` in the template HTML
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```